# How do I set/get cross-class variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

I'm creating an application for the iPhone in which I need to transfer information from variables between views/classes.  What is the best way to do this (without utilizing CoreData/persistent storage)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok--so after more research I discovered [Singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Objective_C).  I implemented that as its own class, then every time I instantiated it, it saved as the correct variables.